# Similar like Php session for Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm newbie for Android Studio & Java, i'm PHP user.
Just want to know how to do like PHP session in Android Studio.
No matter which Activity i go to, i can easily get the session value example like the User ID. (session["USERID"])

now the method i using is putting extra everytime i call for another activity.
i'm sure there will be a better way to do this.

anyone have any good suggestion?

PS: I google around and it keep return me PHP session tutorial/example/etc but not for Android Studio....(may be i enter work #keyword or sentence)

Thank You Very Much

---

Thanks to  fillobotto & Arshid KV

here is my code

first_main activity

```
sharedpreference = getSharedPreferences(BIZInfo, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedpreference.edit().putString(userid, "12345");
sharedpreference.edit().commit();
```

second_main activity

```
sharedpreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String restoredText = sharedpreference.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
   sp_name = sharedpreference.getString("userid", "No name defined");
}
Log.i("TAG", "onCreate: [" + sp_name + "]");
```

log show empty value/nothing...

what went wrong!?

Comment: Maybe [SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) could do the trick. Is this what you meant?

Comment: i think i JUST try this but i dont know how to retrieve it from another activity... any good and easy to understand reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` as session in `php`

**Demo code :-**

> Setting values in Preference:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Arshid");
 editor.putInt("Age", 22);
 editor.commit();
```

> Retrieve data from preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
  int Age = prefs.getInt("Age", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really near to the solution. This is what I use:

```
public static String getSession(Activity context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPreferences.getString("session", null);
}

public static void setSession(Activity context, String session) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("session", session);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I'm actually passing the `Activity`to get `SharedPreferences`, but in this way you will obtain an instance of the object which is not activity-related.